# ui->textEdit->setPlainText(line) (no member named 'TextEdit' in 'Ui::TextFinder' )

Tags: c++, qt

```
#include "textfinder.h"
#include "ui_textfinder.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QTextEdit>

TextFinder::TextFinder(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TextFinder)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

TextFinder::~TextFinder()
{
    delete ui;
}

void TextFinder::on_findButton_clicked()
{

}
void TextFinder::loadTextFile()
{
    QFile inputFile(":/input.txt");
    inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QTextStream in(&inputFile);
    QString line = in.readAll();
    inputFile.close();

    ui->textEdit->
}
```

I have problem with ui->textEdit->setPlainText(line) (no member named 'TextEdit' in 'Ui::TextFinder' )

there is an image of ui

[image]

Comment: Have you tried compiling it anyway? The `ui_file.h` usually are generated each time you compile from the ui xml file, so after you add something the header is not updated right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ui_textfinder.h` is generated each time you compile, so autocomplete might not work after updating the `textfinder.ui` file even if the widget has been added.

To solve the issue just compile the project anyway, this way `ui_textfinder.h` is updated and autocomplete works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile your project once again.